# How to properly constrain `arbitrary` UUID-Generation?

Tags: haskell, uuid, quickcheck

I'm trying to create `Arbitrary` instances for some of my types to be used in `QuickCheck` property testing. I need randomly generated UUIDs, with the constraint that all-zero (`nil`) UUIDs are disallowed - that is, `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`. Therefore, I set up the following generator:

```
nonzeroIdGen :: Gen UUID.UUID
nonzeroIdGen = arbitrary `suchThat` (not . UUID.null)
```

Which I use in an `Arbitrary` instance as follows:

```
instance Arbitrary E.EventId where
    arbitrary = do
        maybeEid <- E.mkEventId <$> nonzeroIdGen
        return $ fromJust maybeEid
```

In general, this is unsafe code; but for testing, with supposedly guaranteed nonzero UUIDs, I thought the `fromJust` to be ok.

`mkEventId` is defined as

```
mkEventId :: UUID.UUID -> Maybe EventId
mkEventId uid = EventId <$> validateId uid
```

with `EventId` a new type-wrapper around `UUID.UUID`, and

```
validateId :: UUID.UUID -> Maybe UUID.UUID
validateId uuid = if UUID.null uuid then Nothing else Just uuid
```

To my surprise, I get failing tests because of all-zero UUIDs generated by the above code. A `trace` in `mkEventId` shows the following:

```
00000001-0000-0001-0000-000000000001
Just (EventId {getEventId = 00000001-0000-0001-0000-000000000001})

00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Nothing
    Create valid Events. FAILED [1]
```

The first generated ID is fine, the second one is all-zero, despite my `nonzeroIdGen` generator from above. What am I missing?

Comment: What's the type of `mkEventId`? I don't understand how that expression type-checks...

Comment: @MarkSeemann, thanks for your help! I added the type signatures.

Comment: Trying to reproduce your code, `mkEventId` doesn't type-check, but it does if I change it to `mkEventId u = EventId <$> validateId u`.

Comment: Ah, newbie error trying to make things point-free when posting here.

Comment: From the current description of the problem, I can't tell what goes wrong... It looks okay. Then, you don't show the definition of the test that fails. It might help if you post a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)...

Comment: @MarkSeemann, thanks for your effort! The test does not fail - it doesn't get that far. `fromJust` in the `Arbitrary` instance throws an error because `validateId` returns `Nothing` because the generated UUID is Nil. I don't have working code right now because I'm trying to incorporate your suggestion below.

Comment: @MarkSeemann, I refactored my code to follow your suggestion below. Now, the weird behaviour described above does not appear any more. I am not sure what caused the problem. However, I would blame it on some beginner mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally find that in cases like this, using `newtype`s to define instances of `Arbitrary` composes better. Here's one I made for valid `UUID` values:

```
newtype NonNilUUID = NonNilUUID { getNonNilUUID :: UUID } deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Arbitrary NonNilUUID where
  arbitrary = NonNilUUID <$> arbitrary `suchThat` (/= nil)
```

You can then compose other `Arbitrary` instances from this one, like I do here with a `Reservation` data type:

```
newtype ValidReservation =
  ValidReservation { getValidReservation :: Reservation } deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Arbitrary ValidReservation where
  arbitrary = do
    (NonNilUUID rid) <- arbitrary
    (FutureTime d) <- arbitrary
    n <- arbitrary
    e <- arbitrary
    (QuantityWithinCapacity q) <- arbitrary
    return $ ValidReservation $ Reservation rid d n e q
```

Notice the pattern match `(NonNilUUID rid) <- arbitrary` to deconstruct `rid` as a `UUID` value.

You may notice that I've also created a `ValidReservation` `newtype` for my `Reservation` data type. I [consistently do this to avoid orphan instances](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/09/02/naming-newtypes-for-quickcheck-arbitraries), and to avoid polluting my domain model with a QuickCheck dependency. (I have nothing against QuickCheck, but test-specific capabilities don't belong in the 'production' code.)

All the code shown here is [available in context on GitHub](https://github.com/ploeh/reservation-api-slice-haskell/blob/master/test/ReservationAPISpec.hs).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try to refactor my code in this way.

Comment: What exactly doe you mean by "composes better"?

Comment: @UlrichSchuster That's it's easy to reuse e.g. `NonNilUUID`'s `Arbitrary` instance to define more complex `Arbitrary` instances, as demonstrated above. Notice also the other test-specific `newtype` wrappers in the example: `FutureTime` and `QuantityWithinCapacity`.